# ceph-mon fails to start on rasberry pi (raspbian 8.0)

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, storage, raspbian, ceph

I recently purchased 3 raspberry pi nodes to create a small storage cluster to test with at my home.  I found a couple of procedures on setting this up so it appears folks have successfully done [this](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/ceph-raspberry-pi-rahul-vijayan/)!

I am running Raspbian GNU/Linux 8.0 (jessie).  I'm using ceph-deploy to install the cluster and it appears to install version 10.2.5-7.2+rpi1 of the ceph ARM packages.

When I try to start the ceph-mon service I get the following error from systemd:

```
Dec 14 19:59:46 ceph-master systemd[1]: Starting Ceph cluster monitor daemon...
Dec 14 19:59:46 ceph-master systemd[1]: Started Ceph cluster monitor daemon.
Dec 14 19:59:47 ceph-master ceph-mon[28237]: *** Caught signal (Segmentation fault) **
Dec 14 19:59:47 ceph-master ceph-mon[28237]: in thread 756a5c30 thread_name:admin_socket
Dec 14 19:59:47 ceph-master systemd[1]: ceph-mon@ceph-master.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=11/SEGV
Dec 14 19:59:47 ceph-master systemd[1]: Unit ceph-mon@ceph-master.service entered failed state.
Dec 14 19:59:47 ceph-master systemd[1]: ceph-mon@ceph-master.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 14 19:59:47 ceph-master systemd[1]: Stopping Ceph cluster monitor daemon...
Dec 14 19:59:47 ceph-master systemd[1]: Starting Ceph cluster monitor daemon...
Dec 14 19:59:47 ceph-master systemd[1]: Started Ceph cluster monitor daemon.
Dec 14 19:59:49 ceph-master ceph-mon[28256]: *** Caught signal (Segmentation fault) **
Dec 14 19:59:49 ceph-master ceph-mon[28256]: in thread 75654c30 thread_name:admin_socket
Dec 14 19:59:49 ceph-master ceph-mon[28256]: ceph version 10.2.5 (c461ee19ecbc0c5c330aca20f7392c9a00730367)
Dec 14 19:59:49 ceph-master ceph-mon[28256]: 1: (()+0x4b1348) [0x54fae348]
Dec 14 19:59:49 ceph-master ceph-mon[28256]: 2: (__default_sa_restorer()+0) [0x768bb480]
Dec 14 19:59:49 ceph-master ceph-mon[28256]: 3: (AdminSocket::do_accept()+0x28) [0x550ca154]
Dec 14 19:59:49 ceph-master ceph-mon[28256]: 4: (AdminSocket::entry()+0x22c) [0x550cc458]
Dec 14 19:59:49 ceph-master systemd[1]: ceph-mon@ceph-master.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=11/SEGV
Dec 14 19:59:49 ceph-master systemd[1]: Unit ceph-mon@ceph-master.service entered failed state.
Dec 14 19:59:49 ceph-master systemd[1]: ceph-mon@ceph-master.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 14 19:59:49 ceph-master systemd[1]: Stopping Ceph cluster monitor daemon...
Dec 14 19:59:49 ceph-master systemd[1]: Starting Ceph cluster monitor daemon...
Dec 14 19:59:49 ceph-master systemd[1]: Started Ceph cluster monitor daemon.
Dec 14 19:59:50 ceph-master ceph-mon[28271]: *** Caught signal (Segmentation fault) **
Dec 14 19:59:50 ceph-master ceph-mon[28271]: in thread 755fcc30 thread_name:admin_socket
Dec 14 19:59:50 ceph-master systemd[1]: ceph-mon@ceph-master.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=11/SEGV
Dec 14 19:59:50 ceph-master systemd[1]: Unit ceph-mon@ceph-master.service entered failed state.
Dec 14 19:59:50 ceph-master systemd[1]: ceph-mon@ceph-master.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 14 19:59:50 ceph-master systemd[1]: Stopping Ceph cluster monitor daemon...
Dec 14 19:59:50 ceph-master systemd[1]: Starting Ceph cluster monitor daemon...
Dec 14 19:59:50 ceph-master systemd[1]: ceph-mon@ceph-master.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start.
Dec 14 19:59:50 ceph-master systemd[1]: Failed to start Ceph cluster monitor daemon.
Dec 14 19:59:50 ceph-master systemd[1]: Unit ceph-mon@ceph-master.service entered failed state.
```

I'm looking for guidance here as I'm not sure why this doesn't work.  I am using the following URLs for my apt repos:

```
root@ceph-master:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ testing main contrib non-free rpi

root@ceph-master:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ceph.list
deb https://download.ceph.com/debian-jewel/ jessie main
```

Has anyone else tried this and had similar problems?  Any advice on how to proceed or work around this issue?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/), [Internet of Things Stack Exchange](http://iot.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Sure, no problem.  I think the Ceph docs pointed me specifically to stackoverflow, but I hear ya.  Thanks for the guidance!